# What Permission Is Needed For create_api_key for AWS API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to create an HTTP proxy from an API Gateway to a lambda function which will call [create_api_key()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/apigateway.html#APIGateway.Client.create_api_key) from boto3. However, I'm having a hard time finding any docs on exactly what IAM permissions I need to enable to allow my lambda function to call create_api_key().

Comment: What have you tried so far and what were the error messages?